# How can I serve my Vuejs front end files from my node/express server?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

Basically, I have two routes with express one for the home page and other for the admin page, but I cannot find a good documentation on how to combine `Vuejs` and `Express`, so I can serve at the same time both pages assuming that both have different UI's, so the components are not constructed the same.

Comment: Are they 2 separate `vue-cli` projects? What do the routes look like? Are you using `vue-router` in history mode?

Comment: I am not using the `vue-router` (not yet, since I my app doesn't have multiple pages/components to render) and probably I would have to make 2 separate `vue-cli` projects only if I finally use the vue-cli webpack templates.

Answer (score 1):

To use `vue-router` and avoid running into 404 issues, your `express.js` has to have a fallback that serves the index.html. Here is a `vue` guide on how to do it https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: I solve this long time ago by doing: `app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
})` thanks anyways.

Comment: URL is now https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

To serve static files with `expressjs` you need to use the [static middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static).

It accepts the directory name as the first argument. This directory shall contain all the static files to be served.

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
app.use(express.static('public')); // NAME OF THE DIRECTORY IS PUBLIC

const serverPort = 3000;

const respHttpOptions = {
    root: `public/`,
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'dina-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'my-xxx-header': true
    }
};
app.get('/', (req, resp) => { // HANDLE THE REQUEST HERE
    resp.sendFile('index.html', respHttpOptions, (err) => {
        // SEND INDEX.HTML INSIDE PUBLIC DIRECTORY
        if (!err)
            console.log(sucL(`Served index.html`));
        else
            console.log(errL(`Failed to serve index.html ${err}`));
    })
});

try {
    app.listen(serverPort);
    console.log(sucL(`Server started at ${serverPort}`));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(errL(e));
}
```

There is no distinction for vuejs! You could have multiple directories inside the static directory.

Comment: if you do this there: app.use(express.static('public')); there is no point of doing this: app.get('/', (req, resp) => {... since when I run the server and open a window at the specified port by default would send the index.html file. I know that I can serve files that way but if you are using the vuejs webpack templates it came with a different server at port 8080 and I don't need to run this server I needed to run on my express local server.